# PHP session_destroy() isn't working

Tags: php, session

This is frustrating, I've been working with PHP Sessions for a long time and haven't had this problem until now. I'm working on a basic login/logout script using PHP.

Here's what I have for my logout script.

**logout.php**

```
<?php
     session_start();
     unset($_SESSION['email']);
     session_destroy();
     header("Location:login.php"); 
?>
```

And therefore my **login.php** script has the following code:

**login.php**

```
// I send the user to logged_in.php if the session already exists.
if(isset($_SESSION['email'])) header("Location:logged_in.php");

if(pass and username are correct){
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    session_write_close();
    header('Refresh: 1; logged_in.php');
}
```

Now when I login and I'm redirected to **logged_in.php** page, form there when I go to **logout.php** page, instead of being redirected to **login.php** it goes back to **logged_in.php**.

Which means that when it arrives to **login.php** the session still exists and it enters the following if statement in **login.php**

```
if(isset($_SESSION['email'])) header("Location:logged_in.php);
```

Comment: you have to miss parenthesis at `unset($_SESSION['email'];`

Comment: Oh that was just a typo while pasting the code. The syntax is all correct in the text editor.

Comment: have you been redirected always when you access to `login.php` (independently have you a session or not, try to delete all the php-session files and direct access to the `login.php` at browser's address bar)? .. it's weird suggestion, may be you have additional semicolon after `if-statement`, something like that: `if (isset($_SESSION['email'])); header('Location: logged_in.php');` ? According your source, you have been redirected even without `session_start()`, but if you haven't initialize it, you can't have `$_SESSION` global variable exists.. and I guess you cannot log forever in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like that:

```
session_start();

// I send the user to logged_in.php if the session already exists.
if(isset($_SESSION['email'])) header("Location:logged_in.php");

if(pass and username are correct){
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    session_write_close();
    header('Refresh: 1; logged_in.php');
}
```

Comment: What's the difference between you code and the code I posted under **login.php**?

Comment: @TayabSoomro The `session_start() call.`

Comment: This is the correct answer, in your **login.php** you are not initializing session with `session_start()`. And in your **logout.php** you are unseting the "email" seassion variable. With destroy you are already doing this.

Comment: The result is still the same, even after adding `session_start();`

Answer (score 0):

`session_regenerate_id(true)` worked for me.  I was having the same issue before.  It appears that some browsers do not properly delete the session cookie while they are active.  Regenerating the ID gives you a fresh session, though you should still of course delete your old session as you have.  I'm not quite sure if this is a fix or a workaround, but it works. `session_regenerate_id` will create a new session variable and delete the old one if you set the parameter to true.

Comment: It goes under `session_destory();` in the **logout.php**?

Comment: Correct.  It worked in my logout script.  According to documentation though, you don't have to destroy the session cookie with `session_regenerate_id(true)` in version 5.1.   Any earlier version and you would put it below `session_destroy()` and omit the parameter.

Comment: When I use Safari though, it redirects me back to login.php, but when I manually enter logged_in.php in address bar, it lets me in, but it shouldn't.

Comment: @TayabSoomro in your logged_in.php file you need to add the verification, `if (isset($_SESSION['email']))`.